# Acces an item in a dictionary with a custom object key in vba

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, key

I've got a problem accessing items in a dictionary in vba.

I've the following dictionary:

```
Dim CResults as dictionary
```

I add items:

```
CResults.add currentkey, result
```

`Currentkey` is an object that I created myself from a class called `DCRkey`

```
Private loadcase as long
Private csystem as String
Private node as long
```

and `result` is another object from a class called `DCR`:

```
Private Fs as double
Private C1 as double
Private C2 as double
...
```

Then I try to access an item using

```
Dim accesskey as DCRKey
accesskey.loadcase=10
accesskey.node = 2000
accesskey.csystem="Global"
Sheets("Results").cells(i,1).value= CResults(accesskey).C1
```

That is where I've got the error: `runtime error 424 object required`

Then I thought maybe the key and the item that I search where not imported, so I decided to display my entire dictionary on an excel worksheet:

```
Dim testkey as variant
dim i as integer
i=1
with worksheet("Test")
    For each testkey in CResults.keys
        .cells(i,1)=test.node
        .cells(i,2)=test.loadcase
        .cells(i,3)=test.csystem
        .cells(i,4)=Cresults(testkey).C1
        .cells(i,5)=Cresults(testkey).Fs
        if accesskey.loadcase=testkey.loadcase and accesskey.node=testkey.node and accesskey.csystem=testkey.csystem then
            Msgbox "This key is the same as the accesskey"
        End if
        i=i+1
    Next
End with
```

What I see is:

1. The key that I was searching earlier exists in the dictionary : visual check on the sheet
2. The key that I was searching earlier realy exists in the dictionary : `"This key is the same as the acceskey"` is displayed once
3. Accessing an item in the dictionary from the `for each` loop works because C1 and Fs are displayed correctly on the worksheet

Then I thought maybe it is due to the fact that `testkey` is defined as a variant and not a `DCRKey`, so I tried that:

```
dim a as variant
Set a = currentkey
.Cells(i,1) = CResults(a).C1
```

But it doesn't works and I still got the `runtime error 424`.

I also did is try:

```
CResults.exists(accesskey)
```

It returns false and create a new entry in the dictionary (btw I hate when it does that), with the same key as acceskey and an empty item.

So my question is: why accessing an item using a custom type key works in a `for each` loop and not in a standalone call. What have I missed? This code is very similar to the code that I wrote but not exactly the same (for you to understand better). Tell me if you think that the real code could help.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: The real code is pretty much always better than something a bit like what you're actually using. ;)

Comment: One immediate question: are you using the **same object** as the key to access the item as the one you used when you added it to the Dictionary? If not, you would get that error.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand your question. The key is a `DCRKey` instantiation the item itself is a `DCR` instantiation, and i don't really acces the item itself but directly one of its attribute via CResults(accesskey).C1

Comment: See mielk's answer. That's what I was asking - I think you are using a different instance of the `DCRKey` class to access the item. It has to be the **same instance** you used as a key when you added the item.

Comment: I just saw it. I understand now thansk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remember that two instances of a class are not the same one, even if all their properties are set to the same values.

Let's consider the example below:

```
Sub compareSimilarObjects()

    Dim key1 As DCRKey
    Dim key2 As DCRKey

    Set key1 = New DCRKey
    With key1
        .loadcase = 10
        .node = 2000
        .csystem = "Global"
    End With

    Set key2 = New DCRKey
    With key1
        .loadcase = 10
        .node = 2000
        .csystem = "Global"
    End With


    'Debug.Print to check pointer assigne to those variables.
    Debug.Print "Key1: " & ObjPtr(key1)
    Debug.Print "Key2: " & ObjPtr(key2)

End Sub
```

In this example both objects of `DCRKey` class have all the properties set to the same values. However, they are not the same object as you can see after the code below run `Debug.Prints` at the end.

In those `Debug.Print` VBA built-in function `ObjPtr` is used. The purpose of this function is to return pointer to the given object. Each instance of object has its own unique pointer, so if the code below printed two different pointers it means those objects are not the same.

---

Now, let's consider another example:

```
Sub compareSimilarObjects()
    Dim key1 As DCRKey
    Dim key2 As DCRKey

    Set key1 = New DCRKey
    With key1
        .loadcase = 10
        .node = 2000
        .csystem = "Global"
    End With

    Set key2 = key1


    'Debug.Print to check pointer assigned to those variables.
    Debug.Print "Key1: " & ObjPtr(key1)
    Debug.Print "Key2: " & ObjPtr(key2)
    'Now those pointers should be the same.

End Sub
```

Here, we assigned a new instance of class `DCRKey` to the variable `key1` and then we assigned the same object to the variable `key2`. Now `ObjPtr` should return the same value for both `key1` and `key2` since this is the same object, it is just assigned to two different variables.

---

Now, let's go back to dictionaries.

**The way how dictionary search for the key of `Object` type is by its pointer.**

So if you want to find an entry in a dictionary that is added with an object as a key, you need to use exactly the same object (not the object having the same properties).

Example:

```
Sub objectsToDictionaryTest()
    Dim CResults As Dictionary
    Dim accessKey As DCRKey
    Dim key As DCRKey
    Dim value As DCR
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    Set CResults = New Scripting.Dictionary


    'Let's create an object of [DCRKey] class (it will be used as a key when adding to
    'the dictionary) and an object of [DCR] class (it will be used as a value).
    Set accessKey = New DCRKey
    With accessKey
        .loadcase = 10
        .node = 2000
        .csystem = "Global"
    End With

    Set value = New DCR
    With value
        .C1 = 10
        .C2 = 20
        .Fs = 3
    End With


    'Now, let's add a new entry to the dictionary [CResults]
    CResults.Add accessKey, value


    'Let's create the other object of [DCRKey] that have exactly the same properties
    'as object assigned to the variable [accessKey].
    Set key = New DCRKey
    With key
        .loadcase = 10
        .node = 2000
        .csystem = "Global"
    End With



    'Now, let's check how dictionary is acting when we try to find an entry by [accesKey] and [key].
    Debug.Print "[accessKey] exists: " & CResults.Exists(accessKey)         'it should return True.
    Debug.Print "[key] exists: " & CResults.Exists(key)                     'it should return False.

    Debug.Print "[Value for accessKey]: " & CResults.Item(accessKey).Fs     'it should print 3

    'The line below should cause an run-time error 424: Object required.
    Debug.Print "[Value for key]: " & CResults.Item(key).Fs


End Sub
```

Comment: `CResults.Exists(key)` should return `False`, should it not?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very detailed answer. Not sure I like what it implies though. In my case I use the dictionary to store information and access it later, from a different module in different circumstances. That mean I have to find a way to keep the pointer in memory all the time and I cannot recreate a key with wanted values later. I don't see how i can do that. It is the first time I use an object as key, for this special case I needed 3 keys. A DCR (displacement, charge, reaction) is for one node, one load case and one coordinate system. I'll have to figure a way around. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe instead of using a CDRKey object i can use a string like `coordinatesystem & " " & Cstr(loadcase) & " " & cstr(Node)` as key. This should work, shouldn't it? I'll try that for now.

Comment: Yup - I'd typically concatenate the items (with a separator) into one unique string.

Comment: @Matt If you really do want to use an object as the key, maybe you can use nested dictionaries. As a disclaimer, I've never tried this with objects, but I know it can be done with types. For example, have Dict1 contain an integer key with an object reference. Dict2 can have the object reference as the key, with the corresponding reference as it's own value. Call `Dict2(Dict1(1))` to return the value from dict2 that corresponds to the object in dict1 with key `1`

Comment: @ user3561813 That's kind of what i was doing previously. I had a dictionary of nodes with inside : 6 dictionary for each displacement direction, 6 for charges, 6 for reaction, and 2 more. Each dictionary contained custom objects for value in the global coordinate system and in the local coordinate system. But my brained lagged (so did my computer) and i wanted to find something easier. :)