# Exist function in dictionary doesn't work for an object as Key created in a class module

Tags: excel, vba

In my code, in need to store two value in my key to be able to do the analysis i require. And since I didn't want to store everything in an array, i decided to create an object with 2 parameters. But when i run the Exist function of the dictionary with that object "TwoInputs" as the type of Key, I always get that they Key doesn't exist. Can anyone help please?

I added "Option Compare Text" just in case but the exist still return False.
When I run the code line by line and force it to go the If "true" condition, a new Key is still created, don't know why.

This is the class module i created:

```
Private acc As Double
Private act As Variant




'Account property

Public Property Get Account() As Double
    Account = acc
End Property
Public Property Let Account(Value As Double)
    acc = Value
End Property


'Activity property

Public Property Get Activity() As Variant
    Activity = act
End Property
Public Property Let Activity(Value As Variant)
    act = Value
End Property
```

In a normal module i wrote a function to create a TwoInputs object based on two entries:

```
Public Function cTwoInputs(Account As Double, Activity As Variant) As TwoInputs

Set cTwoInputs = New TwoInputs
cTwoInputs.Account = Account
cTwoInputs.Activity = Activity


End Function
```

Then I create a sub where I want to add the 2 informations in a Key if they exist:

```
While dataSheet.Range("dataAgent").Offset(j, 0).Value <> "Project ID:" And dataSheet.Range("dataAgent").Offset(j, 0).Row <= lRow
                If dataSheet.Range("dataAgent").Offset( j, 0).Value = "Activity ID:" Then
                    actName = dataSheet.Range("dataAgent").Offset(j, 1).Value
                End If
                If (dataSheet.Range("dataAgent").Offset(j, 0).Value = "XXXXX" Or dataSheet.Range("dataAgent").Offset(j, 0).Value = "") Then
                    KeyExist.Account = dataSheet.Range("dataAccount").Offset(j , 0).Value
                    KeyExist.Activity = actName
                    If dicBudget.Exists(KeyExist) Then
                        dicBudget(KeyExist) = dicBudget(KeyExist) + dataSheet.Range("dataBudget").Offset(j , 0).Value
                    Else
                        dicBudget.Add cTwoInputs(dataSheet.Range("dataAccount").Offset(j, 0).Value, actName), dataSheet.Range("dataBudget").Offset( j, 0).Value
                    End If
                End If
                j = j + 1
            Wend
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Acces an item in a dictionary with a custom object key in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760830/acces-an-item-in-a-dictionary-with-a-custom-object-key-in-vba)

Comment: I thought a key could only be a string or number

Answer (score 1):

.Exists() method compares objects by their instances not by values of their fields.
So it's better to use primitive types like String, Integer, Double etc. as keys, and not to use custom object as a key. If you really need to use object-key for some purpose than you must be sure that you call .Exists() method on the same object you put to dictionary (e.g. by storing that key in a global variable).

Comment: First of all thank you very much for taking the time to reply. I'm afraid that I didn't quite understand how i would store that key (a TwoInputs object) in a global variable that would make the .Exists() method work? I did try creating a global two input object at the beginning of the module and testing the .Exists() method on it but it still doesn't work

Comment: It should work for the same object. Try to log ObjPtr() function result on your KeyExist object just before putting it as a key to dictionary and before calling .Exists method and you'll find where the object is reinitialized. 
If both ObjPtr results are the same (I wonder if so, but can't test it by myself now) than try to log the pointer of a saved key by it's index (e.g. ObjPtr(dict.Keys()(0))). Maybe object instance is recreated when using .Add method, and you should add objects to dictionary by .Item(key) = value expression.