# Microsoft scripting runtime dictionary using collection as key

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, collections

I have a series of data where each item has a number of values associated with it.  Blocks of items will share these values, then for other items these will change.

I am transferring over the data between databases.  In the old one each item has all of its values stored separately.  In the new database I want to take advantage of the fact that large numbers of items share the same values by storing these sets of values as a configuration.  I am doing this in vba for excel.

To identify what the unique sets of values are I wanted to use a dictionary where the key is a collection.  I got lulled into a false sense of security by it allowing me to do this, however it doesnt manage to identify where keys are identical.

Example code as follows.  Should add just two items to the dictionary but adds all 3.  Am I missing something or just expecting too much of the dictionary?  Would save me a little time if I didnt manually have to compare all the sets.

```
Sub CollectionAsKeyTest()
Dim dic As New Dictionary
Dim col As Collection
Dim i As Integer

dic.CompareMode = BinaryCompare

'Create a collection to add to dictionary:
Set col = New Collection
For i = 1 To 10
    col.Add i * 1
Next i
dic.Add col, "item 1"

'Create a different collection and add as key to dictionary:
Set col = New Collection
For i = 1 To 10
    col.Add i * 2
Next i
If Not dic.Exists(col) Then dic.Add col, "item 2"

'Create a collection which is the same as the first, and try to add to dictionary:
Set col = New Collection
For i = 1 To 10
    col.Add i * 1
Next i
If Not dic.Exists(col) Then dic.Add col, "item 3"

'All three collections are added:
Debug.Print "Number of collections added = " & dic.count
End Sub
```

Comment: Each time col is a new collection so it won't exist in your dictionary.

Comment: Its a new collection each time, but contains the same data..  Doesnt that make it the same?

Comment: Why are you storing the collection as the `Key`? Store your collection as the `Value` and your `Value` as the `Key`

Comment: Objects are equal when they are identical. For example, `Range("A1")` isn't the same as `Range("A2")` even if `Range("A1").Value = Range("A2").Value`. Collections are objects.

Comment: @JohnColeman - I'm having a moment - was my comment correct?

Comment: @SJR I think so, though you could experiment. Personally, I never use a VBA dictionary with keys that are neither strings nor numbers, precisely because the semantics are a bit unintuitive. I am not 100% sure how a collection is hashed to get a key. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32760830/4996248) discusses it.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I think that confirms my suspicions.  I get your example with range, because range has other properties (styles etc) but a collection, I thought, was different.  Reason for using key was it is a quick way to see if that combination of values already exists in the collection.  But turns out that is too lazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, two objects (eg two Collections or two Ranges) are not identically, even when they have the same value(s), and your `dic.Exists(col)` will always fail.

I would suggest to put the collections as *Value* and to write a kind of hash as *key*. If the collections does not contain too much data, simply concatenate all elements of the collection and put this as key, but if you want it a bit more sophisticated, you can calculate a real hash first.

The following code gives you an idea. The hashing routine is copied from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/String_Hashing_in_VBA

```
...
dim hash as string
hash = getHash(col)
If Not dic.Exists(hash) Then dic.Add hash, col
...

Function getHash(c As Collection)

    Dim s As String, i As Long
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        s = s & c(i) & "@@@"
    Next i
    ' Simple: 
    '   getHash = s
    ' Use a real hash:
    getHash = MD5(s)

End Function

Function MD5(ByVal sIn As String) As String

    Dim oT As Object, oMD5 As Object
    Dim TextToHash() As Byte
    Dim bytes() As Byte

    Set oT = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set oMD5 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider")

    TextToHash = oT.GetBytes_4(sIn)
    bytes = oMD5.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))

    MD5 = ConvToHexString(bytes)

    Set oT = Nothing
    Set oMD5 = Nothing

End Function


Private Function ConvToHexString(vIn As Variant) As Variant

    Dim oD As Object

    Set oD = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

      With oD
        .LoadXML "<root />"
        .DocumentElement.DataType = "bin.Hex"
        .DocumentElement.nodeTypedValue = vIn
      End With
    ConvToHexString = Replace(oD.DocumentElement.Text, vbLf, "")

    Set oD = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Great answer.  Thank you!